# mysql_fetch_row not returning fresh updated rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in mysql like below-

```
++++++++++++
+ my_table +
++++++++++++
id
is_done
++++++++++++
```

And I have a PHP script which performs operation like below-

```
<?php

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE is_done=0");

while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
  $id=$res['id'];
  //do something lengthy
  sleep(60);  
  mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET is_done=1 WHERE id='$id'");
}

?>
```

Now, if I manually change one row in mysql and set `is_done=1` for that row, the script still processes that row. How can I adjust my script to read the fresh and updated row from mysql and skip any row that has been marked as done meanwhile?

Comment: You are inside the while that fetches the results already catched. That is why you are not getting freshest ones. To do so, you have to fetch again.

Comment: did you use transactions management. What type of `my_table`?

Comment: If you are doing something *really* lengthy (I notice you have a `sleep(60)` - is a minute realistic?) then you would simply query the database for a single row (`LIMIT 1`) at the beginning of each iteration of the loop. If you are actually only talking about a fraction of a second, that row would just have to wait for the next call to this script before it is processed, because you probably wouldn't want to requery the database many times in quick succession.

Comment: If you want to work with _"up to date data"_ only, you'll simply have to query with a `LIMIT 1`, and process row per row. Also, I wouldn't use `mysql_*` at all (check docs why). I also wouldn't call `sleep` at all. If querying using `LIMIT` time and time again is too slow (which it probably is), you _could_ just query the table prior to updating, to see if the `is_done` field is still set to 0

Answer (score 0):

why Dont you put the simple thing. what is the purpose of using sleep?

```
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET is_done=1 WHERE is_done=0");
```

You dont have query in whole table and change one by one.

if you need to use sleep then try this:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET is_done=1 WHERE is_done=0 and id='$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are worrying about calling unnecessary sql statements I'd suggest to aggregate the id's to an array and update outside the loop (performance):

```
<?php
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE is_done=0");
$ids = array();
while($res=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
$ids[]=$res['id'];
//do something lengthy
sleep(60);
}
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET is_done=1 WHERE id IN ('".implode("','", $ids)."')");
?>
```

MySQL won't do anything for rows that are already contains the new data (no affected rows where is_done=1).

If it's the actions you are doing you are worrying about you can use either [Transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) to make sure the actions you are doing are Atomic, or [Table Locking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) to make sure no changes are taking place while the script is running.